# Problem with lengths(st_intersects(st_buffer(x, 500), y))

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, intersection, r-sf

So I have two datasets. The first properati_santa_rita which is created in this way:

```
barrios <- st_read('https://bitsandbricks.github.io/data/CABA_barrios.geojson')

Properati = vroom::vroom("https://storage.googleapis.com/properati-data-public/ar_properties.csv.gz")

properati_CABA_Propiedades<- Properati  %>% 
  filter(lat !="na", 
         lon != "na") 

properati_CABA_Propiedades <- st_as_sf(x = properati_CABA_Propiedades, 
                                       coords = c("lon", "lat"),  
                                       crs = 4326) 
properati_CABA_Propiedades <- properati_CABA_Propiedades[!duplicated(properati_CABA_Propiedades$title),] 

santa_rita = barrios %>% 
  filter(BARRIO =="VILLA SANTA RITA") 

properati_santa_rita = st_intersection(properati_CABA_Propiedades, santa_rita)
```

The second object "plazas" is created like this

```
# edit - read data before using it
espaciosverdes <- st_read('http://cdn.buenosaires.gob.ar/datosabiertos/datasets/espacios-verdes/espacio-verde-publico.geojson')

plazas =  espaciosverdes %>% 
  filter(clasificac == "PLAZA")
```

I want to know how many properties are in a 500 meter radius of plazas. I have tried these.

```
plazas_clean <- st_transform(plazas, crs = 4326)
plazas_clean <- st_make_valid(plazas)
plazas_buffer = st_buffer(plazas_clean,500)

properati_santa_rita <- st_transform(plazas, crs = 4326)
plazas_clean <- st_transform(plazas_clean, crs = 4326)

properati_santa_rita = properati_santa_rita %>%
  mutate(plazas = sum(as.integer(st_within(properati_santa_rita, plazas_buffer))))
```

> Error in `stopifnot()`:
> ! Problem while computing `plazas = sum(as.integer(st_within(properati_santa_rita,   plazas_buffer)))`.
> Caused by error in `s2_geography_from_wkb()`:
> ! Evaluation error: Found 4 features with invalid spherical geometry.
> [21] Loop 16 is not valid: Edge 40 has duplicate vertex with edge 44
> [25] Loop 30 is not valid: Edge 45 has duplicate vertex with edge 49
> [56] Loop 15 is not valid: Edge 47 has duplicate vertex with edge 51
> [230] Loop 5 is not valid: Edge 280 has duplicate vertex with edge 300.
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. properati_santa_rita %>% ...
> 2. base::stop(`<Rcpp::v_>`)

And then

```
properati_santa_rita <- st_transform(plazas, crs = 3857)
plazas_buffer <- st_transform(plazas_buffer, crs = 3857)

properati_santa_rita = properati_santa_rita %>% 
  mutate(plazas = sum(as.integer(st_within(properati_santa_rita, plazas_buffer))))
```

> Error in `stopifnot()`:
> ! Problem while computing `plazas = sum(as.integer(st_within(properati_santa_rita,   plazas_buffer)))`.
> Caused by error:
> ! 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. properati_santa_rita %>% ...
> 2. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
> 3. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
> 4. mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
>    Error in stopifnot(!inherits(x, "sf"), !missing(sf_column_name), !missing(agr)) :
>
> Caused by error:
> ! 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

I have also tried:

```
properati_santa_rita$plaza_entorno = lengths(st_intersects(st_buffer(properati_santa_rita, 500), plazas_clean))
```

But instead of returning the dataset of properati_santa_rita it gives me the plazas dataset back with the extra column.

On the other hand

```
properati_santa_rita <- st_transform(plazas, crs = 4326)
plazas_clean <- st_transform(plazas_clean, crs = 4326)

properati_santa_rita = properati_santa_rita %>% mutate(plaza_entorno = lengths(st_intersects(st_buffer(plazas_clean, 500), properati_santa_rita)))
```

throws

> "Error in stopifnot(!inherits(x, "sf"), !missing(sf_column_name), !missing(agr)) :
> Caused by error in `s2_geography_from_wkb()`:
> ! Evaluation error: Found 4 features with invalid spherical geometry.
> [21] Loop 16 is not valid: Edge 40 has duplicate vertex with edge 44
> [25] Loop 30 is not valid: Edge 45 has duplicate vertex with edge 49
> [56] Loop 15 is not valid: Edge 47 has duplicate vertex with edge 51
> [230] Loop 5 is not valid: Edge 280 has duplicate vertex with edge 300."

Finally

```
properati_santa_rita <- st_transform(plazas, crs = 3857)
plazas_clean <- st_transform(plazas_clean, crs = 3857)

properati_santa_rita = properati_santa_rita %>% 
  mutate(plaza_entorno = lengths(st_intersects(st_buffer(plazas_clean, 500), properati_santa_rita)))
```

gives me the wrong result.

Any ideas?

I am trying to get in object A a new column called entorno_plazas that is the result of an intersection between object A points and object B polygons. There are points that intersect with more than one polygon. If for example a point is within 500 meters of 3 plazas I want the new column to show "3".

Comment: It would be helpful if you separate the lines of code. So many of the functions are on the same line.

Comment: How big is this `Properati` data because I'm 300MB into its download and I'm thinking about giving up...ok I gave up at 600MB. Do you really need all that data to replicate your problem?

Comment: Given this is a small area I would work only in a projected local coordinate system (and not 3857, either use a local UTM zone or a national/state grid system for this place) and switch of spherical geometry with `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`.